# How to Connect Azure VM to a concrete app in company VPN?

Tags: azure, vpn

we are currently trying to set up a small solution:

- we have a VM in the customer company network, where we want to use an application via RDP.
- customer has a VPN gateway in front, which is simply used with username and password via vpn.customer.com and connected via SSTP over windows
- we have a Azure Windows Server 2016 VM where UiPath RPA solution is running
- this VM should be able to login to the corporate VPN and RDP into the application and automate stuff there
- we need to RDP on our Azure VM with our laptops, that are NOT in the corporate VPN

We don't get it to run. We tried setting up the VPN on our Azure VM but as soon as it is established, we lose the RDP connection to the VM - obviously.

But HOW can we solve this? We've seen, there is something like VPN Gateway, but it seems to work only with certificate files?!

Answer (score 0):

Azure VPN gateways support RADIUS, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-radiuis-mfa-nsp .